# How can I start the rails server in parallel with the webpack server so that I can kill both at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, webpack, terminal

I'm looking for a way to spin up the rails development server in parallel with the webpack server. The problem is that if I run one of them in the background, when I `Ctrl^C` to close everything, one process continues to run in the background and can cause some odd behavior involving the addresses being in use.

I have tried this:

```
$ rails s & bin/webpack-dev-server

// rails and webpack running in parallel

$ sudo lsof -n -i :3000 -i :3035 | grep LISTEN

ruby    26847 username   13u  IPv4 0xa889e9178532bffd      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci (LISTEN)
ruby    26847 username   14u  IPv6 0xa889e91781b9ae3d      0t0  TCP [::1]:hbci (LISTEN)
node    26848 username   19u  IPv4 0xa889e9178e468ffd      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:fjsv-gssagt (LISTEN)
```

But as you can see, when you attempt to kill the process with `Ctrl^C`, there are still processes running on the port.

```
$ sudo lsof -n -i :3000 -i :3035 | grep LISTEN

ruby    26847 username   13u  IPv4 0xa889e9178532bffd      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:hbci (LISTEN)
ruby    26847 username   14u  IPv6 0xa889e91781b9ae3d      0t0  TCP [::1]:hbci (LISTEN)
```

I know that I could simply run these in separate terminals and kill both processes individually, but I would like to be able to create a yarn script that runs them both using something like `yarn start`.

Comment: Just use foreman: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

Comment: Yes @QNester, foreman will work just fine.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without foreman?

Comment: Why wouldn't Rails start Webpack on its own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install `foreman` gem, instructions [here](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).

Then create a `Procfile` and add the startup scripts to it.

```
web: bin/webpack-dev-server
api: rails s
```

To start the servers run `foreman start`.

To kill all processes use `Ctrl^C`, if it fails run `killall "foreman: master"`.